# OpenSMILE Batch Processing

Tags: audio, cmd, batch-processing, feature-extraction

I have successfully installed [openSMILE](https://www.audeering.com/opensmile/) for extracting features of a wav file (audio).

`SMILExtract -C config/chroma_fft.sum.conf -I input.wav -O chroma.csv`

I have successfully used this cmdline (I am using Windows 10) command to extract the features of a single audio file.
Now I want to compute features of multiple files at once using OpenSmile, rather than feeding 1000s of filenames and then concatenating the resultant CSV.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is lacking in focus, and information. If you would edit your question to provide some problematic code and a specific reproducible issue it is exhibiting we may have more chance of assisting you.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @Compo, I get your point, but the problem here is, that there is no code, cause this software runs via command line. I think the best-case scenario is to delete the question, as OpenSmile is not a widely used tool.

Comment: You provided a command line to perform a task with an input and output file; that is clear enough. What we need to understand is what you mean by 'Now I want to compute features of multiple files at once'. If you mean that you have thousands of input files, and you effectively need to replace `input.wav` and/or `chroma.csv` for each, using those 'thousands', then you probably need a simple [tag:for-loop]. Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information. There are also thousands of answers on this site alone which use them, so start browsing.

Comment: OpenSMILE supposedly has a way to run batch tasks but is not clear in the documentation. I came here for the same reason, looking for an example of using batch processing with openSMILE. The question is specific to this software and like @astrian I would also prefer to use the built-capabilities rather than just running individual commands in a loop. 
I tried to edit  question but it seems like there an edit queue that is full. IMHO this is a very good question but just needs some clarification.

Comment: Hello @Astrian_72954 Did you find a solution to this problem or not yet?